# Enable Search Suggestion option in Catalog Search

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

In Magento2 Docs, there is this article
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/search-suggestions.html

There is a mention about **Enable Search Suggestion**.

But in Magento 2.2 `Store -> Configurations -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search` there are only these options ( I've checked all scopes )

[image: Magento2 catalog search]

I've checked the `system.xml` file of search module on a clean installation and even github branches of Magento and it seems like these options exists only in docs.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="catalog">
            <group id="seo">
                <field id="search_terms" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Popular Search Terms</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="search" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="500" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Catalog Search</label>
                <field id="engine" canRestore="1">
                    <backend_model>Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Backend\Engine</backend_model>
                </field>
                <field id="min_query_length" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Minimal Query Length</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="max_query_length" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                    <label>Maximum Query Length</label>
                    <validate>validate-digits</validate>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Do you have these options in your Magento2 Panel Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now they are available in magento 2.3.0 Store -> Configurations -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. These options are in **Enterprise Edition** only.

**Not available in Open Source Edition.**

My bad. :)